# Visual Composer Front-end editor disabled

Tags: wordpress, visual-composer

I was wondering you could shed a light to my WordPress premium theme issue. So I have a theme that comes with visual composer plugin. I notice front-end editor is not enabled. I checked the function.php file to enable it, but the code `vc_disable_frontend();` is nowhere to be found.

I contacted the author theme who advised to add `vc_enable_frontend();` at the end of the file. But when I include it, I am getting errors.

I contacted the author again regarding the issues and he as since fail to get back to me. I researched on the web, it is the same steps I was asked to take.

I need it enabled for visual customisation. I can attach the function code on request.

Thanks in advance

Comment: what errors are you getting?

Comment: As above, what errors are you getting when using `vc_enable_frontend();`?

Comment: am sorry for the late reply. having tried to fix it myself, the error doesn't seems to appeared anymore. But here a screenshot of section in my function.php where have added the code `vc_enabled_frontend();` http://prntscr.com/gkl1ux.

Comment: I didn't any error anymore but is not enable still in the admin page http://prntscr.com/gkl267